# Robot framework +jenkins, testing java application

Tags: java, jenkins, robotframework

I'm working on CentOS 6.5, with Jenkins running. I've installed Robot framework plugin for jenkins, installed python 2.7 with Robot Framework (pybot works). I also wrote pretty easy program using NetBeans maven project with one unit test. My goal is to use RF in order to run said test. 
At first i've tried to use Python version of RF, but eventually did it with jar stand-alone. 
So my questions are:

**1. Is it possible to add java libraries with keywords to Python version of RF or do i have to use jar stand-alone?**

**2. If i have to use .jar stand-alone, how can i run working test case on jenkins?**

I've literally tried everything that i've found on this site (that's why eventually test-case worked), but i couldn't find anything else specificaly about what i'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jar edition with jenkins by using execute shell command

```
java -jar robotframework-3.0.jar -P TestedJarName.jar -d FolderForLogs RobotScript.txt
```

This will let you run test script. In script, you have to specify library with keywords - in other words, where in package is you .java file. For example, if you want to test Main.java that is in com.main package, you must write

```
Library      com.main.main
```

Now, you can use all methods from Main.java

If you want just python script that runs maven tests, you just run it through shell pybot testname.txt
In text u need something like that `Run  mvn test` and that's all.